# Retrieve rows with a column value that do not exist in a given list

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a list of values

```
'A', 'B', 'C','D','E',...,'X'.
```

And I have a database column `CHARS` that is storing the exact values of my list (one value / row) except for `'C'` and `'E'`. So, `CHARS` contains `'A', 'B', 'D',..., 'X'`.

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to return only the rows for `'C'` and `'E'`; the values from my list which are missing from column `CHARS`?

Comment: `list of values` you mean rows or a field with a csv string?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. Do you have a chance to properly normalize your model?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, list of values, is either rows in a Excel file, or just lines in a .txt that I receive and format them as I want in order to compare with rows of my database. Both Answers been helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *list of values* come from outside of the database (e.g. a program), the simplest solution should be the `NOT IN`operator

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE chars NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ..., 'X')
```

(Note: The missing characters in the tuple can't be abbreviated with `...`. So you have write them all.)

If your *list of values* come from a table or query, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE chars NOT IN (SELECT a_char FROM another_table WHERE ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an outer join against a values clause:

```
select i.ch as missing_character
from ( 
  values 
     ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ..., ('X')
) as i(ch)
  left join the_table t on i.ch = t.chars
where t.chars is null
order by i.ch;
```

Note that each char needs to be enclosed in parentheses in the `values` clause to make sure that each one is a single row.

Alternatively you can use the EXCEPT operator:

```
select ch
from ( 
  values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ... , ('X') 
) as i(ch)

except 

select chars
from the_table
order by ch
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/XOUB52627